# Is XML-RPC safe?

Tags: xml, xml-rpc

I have a set of web applications on servers, and an end-user has asked us to enable XML-RPC. The "remote procedure call" portion of XML-RPC scares me a bit. Are my concerns valid (i.e. is it safe to enable/use XML-RPC)? From my searches, I can only find information specific to Wordpress (apparently they deemed XML-RPC safe enough to enable it by default since their version 3.5).

Comment: What's the context here? What would this end-user do with XML-RPC?

Comment: Is it "safe" in what sense? What kinds of users would have access to the servers, and what are you trying to keep them from doing?

Comment: XML-RPC is just an interface; there's nothing inherently different between exposing an API over XML-RPC and exposing that API over a RESTful interface. In either case, you're deliberately exposing an API to a remote user, with all the security impact implicit in that -- impact which depends almost entirely on the contents of the API itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is reasonably safe - in the security sense.

Just lookup the CVEs here:

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=2337&product_id=&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=6&cvssscoremax=6.99&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=3&trc=53&sha=392fdc92d5f65849f45c2e7249d5f9570dfbd711

And you can see that there are more concerns of other features than XMLRPC itself.

(Sorting by the number of exploits descending, you can see that there are none available for XMLRPC, but perhaps for other categories of vulnerabilities like SQL injection etc).

For a balanced view, you can read further (which in my view, is just hype at the moment):

https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2015/10/should-you-disable-xml-rpc-on-wordpress/

https://blogvault.net/disable-xml-rpc-for-better-security/

https://blogvault.net/how-xml-rpc-affects-wordpress-security/